# Django - Extra context in django-registration activation email

Tags: django, django-registration, django-context

I'm using [`django-registration`](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration) for a project of mine.

I'd like to add some extra contextual data to the template used for email activation.

Looking into the [register view source](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/blob/master/registration/views.py#L95), I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any idea ?

Comment: What context do you want to add ?

Comment: This is actually a good question. I just realized that this contextual data I wanted to add is not related to the registration. So I should simply not put it.

Comment: I meant, you could probably add stuff in the template via a template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, you need to write your [own registration backend object](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/default/__init__.py) (easier then is sounds) as well as your [own profile model that inherits from `RegistrationProfile`](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/blob/master/registration/models.py#L150) and make the backend use your custom `RegistrationProfile` instead (This model is where the email templates are rendered and there is no way to extend the context, so they need to be overwritten)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to rewrite the `send_activation_email`
So instead of

```
registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)
```

I wrote this in my Users model

```
def send_activation_email(self, registration_profile):
    ctx_dict = {
        'activation_key': registration_profile.activation_key,
        'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS,
        'OTHER_CONTEXT': 'your own context'
    }
    subject = render_to_string('registration/activation_email_subject.txt',
                               ctx_dict)
    subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
    message = render_to_string('registration/activation_email.txt',
                               ctx_dict)
    self.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
```

And I call it like this

```
user.send_activation_email(registration_profile)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't get what it is your problem but the parameter is just in the code you link (the last one):

```
def register(request, backend, success_url=None, form_class=None,
         disallowed_url='registration_disallowed',
         template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
         extra_context=None)
```

That means you can do it from wherever you are calling the method. Let's say your urls.py:

```
from registration.views import register

(...)

url(r'/registration/^$', register(extra_context={'value-1':'foo', 'value-2':'boo'})), name='registration_access')
```

That's in urls.py, where usually people ask more, but, of course, it could be from any other file you are calling the method.

Comment: `extra_context` is not passed to the authentication backend so it will neither be passed to the email. It is used for the form rendering.